# How to deploy a Find*.cmake file for an Autotools library in the correct place for Yocto?

Tags: cmake, yocto, autotools, bitbake, cmake-modules

I created a new layer over an existing Yocto git for my company project.

In this layer I added a few external `autotools` based libraries.
A few applications need to link against this libraries and the application projects are all `cmake` based.

Taking one of this libraries (e.g. [libcoap](https://github.com/obgm/libcoap)) I could easily find some [`FindCoAP.cmake`](https://github.com/gebart/arrowhead/blob/master/cmake/FindCoAP.cmake) to add to my library recipe.

Now if I was running on PC, it would simply be a matter of placing this `FindCoAP.cmake` file in `cmake`'s `${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules` dir, but how should I, *from inside a `bitbake` recipe* (do_install hook), proceed to make my `Find*.cmake` modules available to anyone's dependent projects?

Should I try to get `Yocto`'s `cmake` `CMAKE_ROOT` variable from system-information like this or is it a safer and more reliable way?

```
do_install_append() {
    cmake --system-information | grep CMAKE_ROOT | cut -d \" -f2
    install -d ${D}/$CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules
    install ${S}/FindCoAP.cmake ${D}/$CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to install your `foo.cmake` during bitbake run into the host directory (outside of OpenEmbeeded directory structure)?

Comment: No, I want to install it to Yocto sysroot so that it can find the library when it comes to compile the cmake application. Thanks for asking @TomasNovotny. Though I am starting to think that having a `FindFoo.cmake` is not going to help me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To ship FindFoo.cmake with non-yet-cmake project**

The ideal way is to update upstream project itself. So you will update your recipe and package `FindFoo.cmake` appropriately.

If you want to do it right now:

1. Add `FindFoo.cmake` to your layer (into the `files` directory next to your recipe).
2. Add that cmake file to `SRC_URI` (i.e. `SRC_URI += "file://FindFoo.cmake"`).
3. Install it in `do_install` into the directory `${D}${datadir}/cmake/Modules/` for example.
4. Package it to the dev package by `FILES_${PN}-dev` variable (see example recipes below).

**To use that cmake by other recipe**

The usual way is to package `.cmake` files into the `${PN}-dev` package. In your case, your application (which depends on the libcoap) will just set `DEPENDS = "libcoap"` and all the needed files (like headers, libraries and cmake file) will be copied (well, hardlinked) to the sysroot of your application.

CMake modules are packaged in various recipes for example:

- [libeigen](http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-support/libeigen/libeigen_3.3.4.bb?h=sumo#n16)
- [opencv](http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-support/opencv/opencv_3.3.bb?h=sumo#n170)
- [json-spirit](http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/json-spirit/json-spirit_4.08.bb?h=sumo#n23)

Your application is cmake based, so you will use `inherit cmake` in the recipe. Native module search path is set in [cmake.bbclass](http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/classes/cmake.bbclass?h=sumo#n107).

(BTW, I do a build test of [libcoap recipe from homeassistant layer](https://github.com/bachp/meta-homeassistant/blob/master/recipes-devtools/libcoap/libcoap_git.bb) and it worked, but obviously there is no cmake shipped.)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Information here is gold so I will accept your answer although it doesn't really answer what I pretended to learn (make a FindFoo.cmake for a non-cmake project to work well). I am sure this is my fault. I am trying to make things the wrong way. Thanks again!

Comment: @j4x oh, sorry, I think that I understand better... I've added the whole "To ship FindFoo.cmake with non-yet-cmake project" section. This answers your question properly? Otherwise I will try again ;-)

Comment: If your first answer is gold, this second part is diamond. I've been trying to move forward without this "FindFoo.cmake" but no lucky (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098050/yocto-autotools-library-cmake-application-linker-error). I think it is not CMake's fault, but I still can't be sure. Thank you very much @TomasNovotny.