# Yocto + Autotools library + CMake application = linker error

Tags: cmake, linker-errors, yocto, autotools

I have a Yocto BSP with my own layer that includes an `autotools` 3rdy part library ([libcoap](https://github.com/obgm/libcoap)).
My application ".bb" file has the following lines, telling `libcoap` is needed:

```
DEPENDS += "libcoap"
RDEPENDDS_${PN} += " libcoap libcoap-dev libcoap-devstatic"
```

I can see the library files are being copied to sysroot:

```
$ ls -l /projects/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/coap-playground/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcoap*
-rw-r--r-- 2 udev udev 286430 Ago 21 13:53 /projects/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/coap-playground/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcoap.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 udev udev    173 Ago 29 14:33 /projects/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/coap-playground/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcoap.so -> ../../projects/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/libcoap/4.1.2+gitAUTOINC+d48ab449fd-r0/image/usr/lib/libcoap.so.4.1.2
-rwxr-xr-x 2 udev udev  38444 Ago 21 13:53 /projects/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/coap-playground/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcoap.so.4.1.2
```

It is not hard to noticed that the symlink is kind of weird:

```
/projects/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/coap-playground/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcoap.so -> ../../projects/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/libcoap/4.1.2+gitAUTOINC+d48ab449fd-r0/image/usr/lib/libcoap.so.4.1.2
```

My `libcoap.bb` contains `inherit relative_symlinks` (otherwise an absolute link to "/projects" is created and bitbake fails) but the symlink created simply prepends "../../" to the original link.

**So... the questions are:**

1. Why do I need `inherit relative_symlinks`? Shouldn't `make install` create a symlink relative to sysroot out of the box?

Generated `Makefile` contains:

```
librootdir = $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/lib
# ...
ln -s $(librootdir)/$(LIBSO).4.1.2 $(librootdir)/$(LIBSO)
```

And I thought `$(DESTDIR)` would already point to the correct place during `bitbake`'s installation...

2. What is the **right** way to fix it? Could it be something wrong at the other side (the application trying to link against `libcoap`)?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Resources**

`libcoap.bb` is based on Internet and quite simple:

```
SUMMARY = "A C implementation of IETF Constrained Application Protocol (RFC 7252)"
DESCRIPTION = "Libcoap provides an implementation of the IETF CoAP protocol"
HOMEPAGE = "http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcoap/"
SECTION = "libs/network"

PROVIDES = "libcoap"

SRCREV = "d48ab449fd05801e574e4966023589ed7dac500b"
# Lookout for PV bump too when SRCREV is changed
PV = "4.1.2+git${SRCPV}"
LICENSE = "GPLv2 | BSD"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${S}/LICENSE.BSD;md5=1164f52f9c4db2c13f681b201010d518 \
                    file://${S}/LICENSE.GPL;md5=4641e94ec96f98fabc56ff9cc48be14b"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

SRC_URI = "git://git.code.sf.net/p/libcoap/code"

inherit autotools-brokensep relative_symlinks

EXTRA_OECONF += "--with-shared"
EXTRA_OEMAKE += "all"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

Comment: How is **CMake** related with your problem?

Comment: The application that is trying to link `libcoap` is CMake'd and I am not sure whether it has any influence in the linker error. Thaks for asking @Tsyvarev